# Grails: Limit input size to one

Tags: grails

I am fairly new to Grails and I'm creating a page where an user can create a "Project". One of the required fields needed to be entered is Category and for the sake of simplicity, I need to make sure that only one category is entered. Is there any easy way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: How to determine whether the user enters one category or more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either do this by using the constraints, see [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/guide/single.html#validation) or you could use some front end validation on the web page, like JQuery validation.